# HIVE json column parse as key and value

Tags: sql, arrays, json, hive, hiveql

In a table having 2 columns and 2 Records :

Record 1 : Column 1 -  my_col value as: `{"XXX": ["123","456"],"YYY": ["246","135"]}` and Column 2 - ID as `A123`

Record 2 : Column 1 -  my_col value as: `{"ZZZ":["333"]}` and Column 2 - ID as `B222`

Expectation :

| Key | Value | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XXX | 123 | A123 |
| XXX | 456 | A123 |
| YYY | 246 | A123 |
| YYY | 135 | A123 |
| ZZZ | 333 | B222 |

The Below query retrieve only keys XXX and YYY, my scenario I have many records. So Query it self identify the key and flatten the values without specify

```
SELECT
t.key,
kv.kval as value,
t.ID
FROM (
SELECT 
 e.key, e.value, --columns from lateral view
 t.id  --column from table  
FROM
    input_df t --add alias
    --move explode to lateral view in the FROM
    lateral view explode(map(
         'XXX',
         split(regexp_replace(get_json_object(my_col,'$.XXX'),'"|\\[|\\]',''),','),
         'YYY',
         split(regexp_replace(get_json_object(my_col,'$.YYY'),'"|\\[|\\]',''),',')
     )) e as key, value --add alias and col names 
) t LATERAL VIEW explode(t.value) kv as kval
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments in the code:

```
WITH input_df AS (
    SELECT 'A123' as id,  '{"XXX": ["123","456"],"YYY": ["246","135"]}' my_col union all
    select 'B222' as id, '{"ZZZ":["333"]}'
)

select split(element,':')[0] key,
       e.value,
       id
from
(
SELECT 
 regexp_replace(e.element,'^\\{|"| *\\[|\\]|\\}$','') element, --remove extra chars to get element like this XXX:123,456
 t.id 
FROM
    input_df t
    lateral view explode(split(my_col,'(?<=\\]) *, *(?=\\")')) e as element --split by comma between ] and " with optional spaces
)s lateral view explode(split(split(element,':')[1],',')) e as value
```

Result:

```
key value   id  
XXX 123     A123
XXX 456     A123
YYY 246     A123
YYY 135     A123
ZZZ 333     B222
```

Comment: when I am using this query with in spark sql , regexp_replace function is not working for [ and ]. Is any alternative function will work?

Comment: @Shan test regexp_replace alone. how it works with shielding. In hive double backslash is used to shield special characters `\\[`. Maybe it should be single slash in Spark. Just test it alone on some string with [ ] and make sure it works. it should. I do not know but you can ask question about function if nothing helps. Another function is replace... not regexp-based.

Comment: regexp_replace(column_name, ']','')as ID, -- working
regexp_replace(column_name, '[','')as ID, -- not working 
Error : 
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 0    [

Comment: @Shan  it needs shielding because in regexp it has special meaning. try backslash `\[`

Comment: If I ran the given query, its working as expected in Hive. But spark not supporting regexp_replace. I will check alternative way in pyspark from dataframe.                                   Thanks for the guidance.